# When opening a Word document in a sharepoint 2010 custom workflow (c# vs2010) i see the following error.

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sharepoint

`System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array. 
   at ConvertWordToPDF.OpenXmlParser.ParseFile(SPFile file) 
   at ConvertWordToPDF.Workflow1.Workflow1.ProcessResumeWorkflow()`

Anyone else run into this? Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

it is very common error when you iterate throught list/library items and your interation go to index that is outside the listitem.count. I dont know how your workflow code looks like so this all what develper can say with seeing only excetpion.